# Adding Array object in mongo response JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mongodb

I want to add array in getting response in mongodb response (data fetching from mongo)

```
    { _id: 23232385,
      CompanyId: 232385,
      CompanyCd: 'MONDLAY',
      CompanyName: 'Company Name ',
      Competition: false,
      ParentCompany: 707,
      CareOf: '',
      AddressLine2: '',
      AddressLine3: '',
      Suite: '',
      City: 'Los Angeles',
      StateCd: 'CA',
      Zip: '90010',
      Title: '',
      Phone: '549-334',
      Extension: '',
      Fax:  '549-9834',
      Comment: '',
      Abrev: '',
      Email: 'example@dsdasd.com' }
```

And want this response in JSON below like format.

```
[      
        { _id: 23232385,
          CompanyId: 232385,
          CompanyCd: 'MONDLAY',
          CompanyName: 'Company Name ',
          Competition: false,
          ParentCompany: 707,
          CareOf: '',
          AddressLine2: '',
          AddressLine3: '',
          Suite: '',
          City: 'Los Angeles',
          StateCd: 'CA',
          Zip: '90010',
          Title: '',
          Phone: '549-334',
          Extension: '',
          Fax:  '549-9834',
          Comment: '',
          Abrev: '',
          Email: 'example@dsdasd.com' }
]
```

Also want something which goes with function. Also trying to implement the same thing with huge data set.
Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post your query also.

Comment: `collection.find().each(function(err, item, response, status) {
       console.log(item)
    Array.from(item).forEach(itemdata => {
        bulk.push({index:{ 
                        _index: esIndexName, 
                        _type: mongoCollectionName,
                    }          
                })
        bulk.push(itemdata)
        }) ` 
here I'm trying to convert `item ` adding object array @SaurabhAgrawal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [cursor.toArray()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/) from mongoDB.

Try like this example:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
MongoClient.connect("url", function (_err, db) {
  var dbo = db.db("myDB");
  dbo.collection("myCollection").find({}).toArray(function (err, result) {
    console.log(result);//this will be array
  })
})
```

Comment: Can you edit the code I shared? Seems like I'm doing some mistake, data is getting lost.

Comment: Everything seems to be fine with your question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58324732/mongo-using-mongoose-in-node-want-to-use-or-and-in-query

can you check this