# mongo using mongoose in node want to use or and in query

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I have a situation where I have to check name of the company and code of the company and if both match with existing than it should say exists, or if one of them is matched in existing db then also it should be saying it exists.
How would I use in mongo?
So if the data receive isDeleted true than I also want to add in if section that checks if not adding than goes for checking id and update, than I also want to pass isDelete, so that if any data received which is previously deleted so that it can set to false again.
how would I handle this delete scenario?

```
{
    "userId":"tt838984984s",
  "company":{
  "addressee" : {
      "addressee" : "Ms.1", 
      "title_name" : "", 
      "salutation" : "Drks:", 
      "comments" : "", 
      "email" : "opus7ent@example.com", 
      "phone" : "123456666", 
      "fax" : "", 
      "extention_group" : "", 
      "ext" : ""
  }, 
  "abbreviation" : "", 
  "care_of" : "", 
  "address_1" : "HELLO2",
  "address_2" : "", 
  "address_3" : "", 
  "state" : "CA", 
  "zip" : "90024", 
  "is_deleted" : true, 
  "company_code" : "ABACAB", 
  "parent_company" : null, 
  "name" : "Abacab", 
  "createdBy" : "Data lolz", 
  "modifiedBy" : "Data", 
  "createdDate" : "2019-08-22T19:10:50.000+0000", 
  "modifiedDate" : "2019-08-22T19:10:50.000+0000", 
  "company_id_legacy" :1246, 
  "__v" : 0, 
  "is_registered_for" : false,

},
}


  is_deleted == false
    if(!isAdd) {
          filter["_id"] ={ "$ne" : id};
           }
        let filter = {
                 name: { $regex: new RegExp(`^${company.name}$`, 'i') },
                 company_code: { $regex: new RegExp(`^${company.company_code}$`, 'i') }
    }
    cModel.find(filter, function (err, docs) {
                            if (docs.length) {
                                result.error = "Name already exists: " + company.name;
                                console.log("Name already exists", null);
                                let resp = api_respose.getSuccessResponse(process.env.WEB_URI, result.error);
                                resolve(resp);
                            }
    else{
     ///saving here
    }
```

Now suppose I pass that JSON, and if there's `is_deleted = false` (this is Json while adding new entry in db)
And now if there's some old entry with `name` or `company_code` exists in db with `is_delete =true` then it throws error that *name already exits*

Now my question is how to resolve this scenario? Like I want to overwrite that file with new entry or is there any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If I have correctly understood, you need using `$or` inside of `$and` function in Mongodb or mongoose, both of them supports these two functions. For example (in mongoose):

```
cModel.find(
        {
            $and: [
                {
                    $or: [
                        { name: { $regex: new RegExp(`^${company.name}$`, 'i') } },
                        { company_code: { $regex: new RegExp(`^${company.company_code}$`, 'i') } }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    is_delete: true
                }
            ]
        }, function (err, docs) { 
            if(docs){
                // throw error!
            } if (!docs) {
                // enter your new doc here with cModel.create(yourDoc, function(error, data){});
            }
        }
    );
```

complete documentation for this function is here:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/

Comment: I've update the question with delete scenario to see if you can help with that?

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't understand what do you want exactly. Would you explain more about it? I'll be so happy to help you. Thanks.

Comment: Updated the question with JSON and explanation

Comment: With this code when I update same JSON passing `_id` at that when I keep name which is already exits in db then it allow to create, rather than throwing an error of name already exits

Comment: First, you must check if such a document exists or not, if no, then you can insert. With the query I've written above, you can find out it exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $or operator

```
  let filter = {
     "$or":[
             name: { $regex: new RegExp(`^${company.name}$`, 'i') },
             company_code: { $regex: new RegExp(`^${company.company_code}$`, 'i') 
            ]
}
}
cModel.find(filter, function (err, docs) {
                        if (docs.length) {
                            result.error = "Name already exists: " + company.name;
                            console.log("Name already exists", null);
                            let resp = api_respose.getSuccessResponse(process.env.WEB_URI, result.error);
                            resolve(resp);
                        }
else{
 ///saving here
}
```

refer https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/ for more info

Comment: I've update the question with delete scenario to see if you can help with that?